# Cannot assign value of type NSMutableArray to type UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an iOS audio app as a learning project. I'm having a problem in one of the functions, which checks if the player is playing or paused/stopped. If it's playing it should change the button in the button bar to a "pause" button, or if it's paused or stopped, change the button to a "play" button. I am assigning the button bar items to a variable "items" as a NSMutableArray, then make the necessary change to the button, then assign "items" back to the button bar items to update the display.

In my code I am getting an error on the line:

```
self.toolbar.items = items
```

The error message is

> Cannot assign value of type NSMutableArray to Type UIBarButtonItem

I assume that I need to cast the NSMutableArray, I've tried using Array, and when I do the error goes away but the buttons break.

The related parts of my code are:

```
@IBOutlet weak var toolbar: UIToolbar!

@IBOutlet var playButton: UIBarButtonItem!


@IBAction func playPausePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let playbackState = self.player.playbackState as MPMusicPlaybackState
    let items = NSMutableArray(array: self.toolbar.items!)
    if playbackState == .Stopped || playbackState == .Paused{
        self.player.play()
        items[2] = self.pauseButton
    } else if playbackState == .Playing{
        self.player.pause()
        items[2] = self.playButton
    }
    self.toolbar.items = items
}
```

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: playButton was created inside the Storyboard editor. pauseButton was declared as a variable within the ViewController class, 

var pauseButton: UIBarButtonItem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because `NSMutableArray` is not related to Swift `Array`

Why not using the native property directly? Due to reference semantics it's not necessary to create a temporary array.

```
@IBAction func playPausePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let playbackState = self.player.playbackState as MPMusicPlaybackState
    var items = self.toolbar.items!
    if playbackState == .Stopped || playbackState == .Paused{
        self.player.play()
        items[2] = self.pauseButton
    } else if playbackState == .Playing{
        self.player.pause()
        items[2] = self.playButton
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach worked for me, thank you! I added some code to set the system item property, after that works great!

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that you could do better. Do you really need to switch between two different buttons for your `items[2]` ?

`UIBarButtonItem` can be used pretty much like a regular `UIButton` with different states. I'm assuming you'd want to switch between a play and pause image whenever your player is paused/playing. You could do this by setting two different images to your UIBarButtonItem (`setBackgroundImage(_:forState:barMetrics:)`) then by setting the appropriate state when your playbackState changes.

Comment: This approach worked for me, the only drawback was the use of real estate with two rather than one button. But it did open my eyes to this functionality, thank you!